# How to map multiple n:m doctrine relationships

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine

This is my relationship: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYMFJ.png

Hello, I have this relationship, I have mapped one relationship (List_has_Doc) on doctrine with a bidirectional relationship with @ManyToMany  but how can I map the other two ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use as many @ManyToMany relationships as you need. So you could have something like

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="list")
 */
class List{
   //other definitions

   /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Doc", invertedBy="flaggedDocList")
    * @JoinTable(name="List_flagged_Doc",
    *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="flagged_doc_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
    *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="flagged_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    * )
    */
    protected $flaggedDocs;


   /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Doc", invertedBy="requestedDocList")
    * @JoinTable(name="List_requested_Doc",
    *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="requested_doc_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
    *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="requested_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    * )
    */
    protected $requestedDocs;

   /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Doc", invertedBy="ownedDocList")
    * @JoinTable(name="List_owned_Doc",
    *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="owned_doc_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
    *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="owned_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    * )
    */
    protected $ownedDocs;
}


/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="doc")
 */
class Doc{
    //...other definitions
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="List", mappedBy="flaggedDocs")
     */
     protected $flaggedDocList;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="List", mappedBy="requestedDocs")
     */
     protected $requestedDocList;


    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="List", mappedBy="ownedDocs")
     */
     protected $ownedDocList;
}
```

Might require to specify @JoinTable in Docs class as well, can't test it now.